# Disabling the closest dropdown menu in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like the user to be able to select a pizza type using the `.pizza` dropdown menu and then to enable the `.pizzaSize` menu next to it. I cannot use the class selector as the form is going to be cloned later on. Here is what I've done so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="pizzaForm">
    <fieldset>
        <form class="pure-form">
        <legend>Pizza</legend>
        <label><b>Pizza Type: &nbsp;</b></label>
        <select class="pizza">
            <option>Please Select:</option></option>
            <option name="margarita">Margarita</option>
            <option name="deep-pan">Deep Pan</option>
            <option name="stuffed-crust">Stuffed Crust</option>
        </select>
            <span style="float:right">
            <label><b>Pizza Size: &nbsp;</b></label>
            <select class="pizzaSize" disabled>
                <option data-price="0">Please Select:</option></option>
                <option name="e-small" data-price="4.99">Extra Small - £4.99</option>
                <option name="small" data-price="5.99">Small - £5.99</option>
                <option name="medium" data-price="6.99">Medium - £6.99</option>
                <option name="large" data-price="8.99">Large - £8.99</option>
                <option name="e-large" data-price="9.99">Extra Large - £9.99</option>
                <option name="f-size" data-price="10.99">Family Size - £10.99</option>
            </select>
            </span>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset style = "border-top:0px">
    <form class="pure-form">
        <legend><b>Toppings (99p Each): &nbsp;</b></legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="onions" disabled>Onions</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mushrooms" disabled>Mushrooms</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="peppers" disabled>Peppers</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="olives" disabled>Olives</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="garlic" disabled> Garlic</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="peperoni" disabled>Peperoni</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cheese" disabled>Pesto</input>
    </form>
    </fieldset>
    <h2> £0.00 </h2>
    <button class="removePizza">Remove Pizza</button>
    <br>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("change",".pizza", function() {
     $(this).closest('.pizzaSize').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `closest()` method to get a reference to the outer container div (with css class `pizzaForm`) element and use `find()` to get a reference to the second drop down.

```
$(document).on("change",".pizza", function() {
     $(this).closest('.pizzaForm').find('.pizzaSize').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/zesuka/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample.

jQuery selection using css class is fine because you are finding the item with the specific class in the parent container relative to the current item. So when you clone a new element, the context of parent will be different(outer container of that cloned copy)